# Are "fibrant arrows" in the category of congruences a special case of some important concept?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Consider the category of congruences $\mathcal X$ of some finitely complete category $\mathcal A$:

Objects are pairs $(A,R)$ such that $R$ is a congruence on $A$. A morphism $(A,R)\to (B,S)$ is a pair $(f : A\to B, \tilde f : R\to S)$ such that $(r_1,r_2)\circ \tilde f = f\times f\circ (s_1,s_2)$, where $R = (r_1,r_2)$ and $S = (s_1,s_2)$ ($\tilde f$ is in fact uniquely determined by $f$).

A morphism $(f,\tilde f)$ is *fibrant*, if the following is a pullback square:

[image]

for $i=1$ or $i=2$ (these two conditions are equivalent).

Fibrant arrows are stable under composition, pullbacks and hence products in $\mathcal X$. They appear in the definition of normal subobjects, among other things.

> Are fibrant arrows in this sense a special case of a more generally useful concept?

They are not the same as *Cartesian* morphisms w.r.t. to the canonical fibration $\mathcal X \to \mathcal A$, but it seems like a property that could be related to this fibration nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Intuitively**, the fibrancy condition on $f$ reads like topological / categorical fibrancy when thinking of $A$ and $B$ as spaces with the identifications coming from $R$ and $S$ being the paths / morphisms. Trying to formulate this ...

**Rigorously**, you can view $\mathcal X$ as a full subcategory of the category of internal categories over $\mathcal A$ where you have the (generalized) notion of Grothendieck fibrations fibered in groupoids / right fibrations, and restricting that to $\mathcal X$ gives your notion of fibration if I didn't miss anything.

Comment: I need some time to understand this, since I'm not really familiar with internal categories yet.

Comment: @StefanPerko Sure, let me know if you'd lile to see more details